# Share filter, sort, and validation logic between backbone and rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, sorting, backbone.js

I find myself regularly having to repeat sorting, filtering, and validation logic across my client side and server side. I want to have all this logic on my rails server side be replicated on backbone so I can do a get request or a client side filter and get the same stuff. Same goes for sorting and validating.

This may be a big question so if anyone has an idea of how to do any of these, I would really appreciate it.

Here's an example of what I mean. This is the backbone filter

```
bySearchTerm: (term) ->
  return @ if term == ''

  filtered = @filter((item) ->
  item.get("name").toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1 or item.get("number").toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
)
  new Evue.Collections.Customers(filtered)
```

But then I needed to replicate it on the server side so someone could do a get request and get the same filtered results.

```
unless params[:search_term].blank?
  @customers = @customers.where("lower(name) LIKE ? or number LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search_term].downcase}%", "%#{params[:search_term].downcase}%")
end
```

This gets out of hand when it comes to all the filters, sorting, and validations. Is switching over to node and using backbone for server and client side logic my answer? Not sure, open to whatever.

Comment: Have you looked into executing js on server side? I'm facing the same problem and i found a way of executing js through the node engine from php. Another solution would be to build store sorting & validation as json and have different paraers on server and client side interpreting the json in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to look into [backbone.paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator) - plugin for Backbone.js, which defines a few new types of collections with enhanced filtering, paging, sorting.

I like the approach with so called `{mode: "client"}` (this can help to avoid replication).

Comment: Great thanks. This might not cover everything but will definitely be a great reference.

Comment: Sure. Try it. Glad it helps.